# Pure C задача санитайзер

Tags: c

Есть задача. условие в комментах. Решает вроде правильно. Valgrind не ругается. Проблема с санитайзером. Что упускаю?

```
/*
 * 209. Minimum Size Subarray Sum
 * Given an array of n positive integers and a positive integer s,
 * find the minimal length of a contiguous subarray of which the
 * sum ≥ s. If there isn't one, return 0 instead.
 *
 * Example:
 * Input: s = 7, nums = [2,3,1,2,4,3]
 * Output: 2
 * Explanation: the subarray [4,3] has the minimal length under the problem constraint.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool min_array(int target, int *nums, int numsSize, int *curr_result) {
    (*curr_result)++;
    bool flag = false;
    if (*nums==target) flag = true;
    else {
        if (*nums>target) flag = false;
        else {
            if (numsSize>1) {
                flag = min_array(target-*nums, nums+1, 
                    numsSize-1, curr_result);
            }

        }
    }
    return flag;
}

int minSubArrayLen(int s, int *nums, int numsSize){
    int curr_result = 0;
    int result = numsSize+1;
    for(int i=0; i<numsSize, result!=1; ++i) {
        curr_result = 0;
        if (min_array(s, nums+i, numsSize, &curr_result) 
            && (curr_result<result)) {
                result=curr_result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int main() {
    int v[] = {2,3,1,2,4,3};
    printf("%d\n", minSubArrayLen(3, v, 6));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какая именно проблема?